# Messed up terminal after installing Angular [altered my zsh $PATH?]

Tags: macos, terminal, path, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just installed Angular and after the default installation (as set out here: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local). After running the standard commands my terminal would not recognise `ng` (so I could not use `ng new my-app`).

To solve this problem I did the following based on a stackoverflow answer:

```
echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
ng --version
```

(I had no knowledge of what PATH was when doing this, or what the command I was running did...)

This worked, and my ng --version returned a result and I was able to build and run an Angular app.

However when I opened a new tab in my terminal all my normal terminal 'styles' (I use zsh) had gone.

[image: new terminal window]

My friend and I tried to resolve the problem, which he felt might be related to my terminal settings (his 'Command (complete path)' read: `/usr/local/bin/zsh`, and mine was `/bin/zsh`). So we tried a few things but none have worked and it might be worse - this included resetting my $PATH based on another stackoverflow answer to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin`.

We also switched back and forth from `/bin/zsh` to `/bin/bash` to try and resolve things, but this did not do anything.

The current state of things is that I cannot run rails commands where I normally could (for example), also things like `ll` (which returns `zsh: command not found: ll`).

This is my `.zsh_history` file:

```
which zsh
which bash
cd code
cd
ls
lsa
ls -a
cat .aliases
vi .aliases
sudo v
sudo vi .aliases
npm install -g angular
npm list
npm install -g @angular/cli
cd code
ls
cd JoshInLisbon
cd ..
JoshInLisbon
ls
mkdir Angular
mkdir Rails
cd rails
ls
cd ..
open
open .
cd WALD
ls
ll
lll
ls -a
cat .git
.git
ls
ls -a
cd ..
..
JoshInLisbon
..
JoshInLisbon
ls
cd Angular\ Projects
ng new my-first-app
which ng
which angula
which angular
echo $path
npm -v
which node
node -v
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng --version
brew install node
node -v
brew postinstall node
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
npm install -g n
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
brew doctor
npm -v
which brew
which npm
brew -v
brew update
npm -v
npm install npm
npm -v
npm install -g npm
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng --version
npm ls --global --depth 0
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
ng --version
cat ~/.bashrc
echo $PATH
ng new my-app
ls
my-app
npm outdated
..
npm install --save core-js@^3
my-app
npm install --save core-js@^3
npm install --save-dev "jasmine-core@>=3.5"
ng serve --open
exit
ls
cd code
ls
codesign
code
ls
cd code
ls
cd JoshInLisbon
ls
cd an
cd Angular\ Projects
ls
cd my-app
code
ng
code
code --
ls
cd ..
cd taaalk
cd ..
cd taaalk_edge
echo $PROMPT
zsh --version
chsh -s
ls
cd code
ls
cd JoshInLisbon
chsh -s /bin/bash
ls
zsh --version
ls -a
cat .zshrc
cd .zshrc
echo $PATH
echo $PATH
vim
cat
ls -a
vim .zshrc
vim .bash_profile
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
echo $PATH
plutil -lint ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
xcode-select --install
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew update
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
ls
ls -a
cat .zshrc.backup
cd code
cd JoshInLisbon
cd Rails\ Projects
rails new thing
rails new thing
echo $PATH
..
ls ..
cd ..
cd ..
cd
ls -a
cat .zshrc.backup
ls -a
cat .zsh_history
vim .bash_profile
ls -a
vim .zcompdump-jmpb-5.7.1
vim zshrc.backup
cat .zshrc
.zsh_history
vim .zshrc
vim .shell.pre-oh-my-zsh
ll
ll -a
```

I can see my `.zshrc` file when I do `ls -a`, however it is empty.

This is my `.bash_history`

```
ls
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
history
which zch
which zsh
echo path
echo $PATH
cd code
cd JoshInLisbon/
rails new project
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
echo $PAtH
echo $PATH
rails new
npm -version
which zsh
cd ..
cd ~
ls
ls -a
cat .szhrc
cat .zshrc
cat .zshrc
ls -a
cat .bash_profile
echo $PATH
cat .zsh_history
cat .bashrc
export PATH=/Users/joshua/.npm-global/bin:./bin:./node_modules/.bin:/Users/joshua/.rbenv/shims:/Users/joshua/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/usr/local/sbin
echo $PATH
which ruby
which zsh
cd code/
cd JoshInLisbon/
cd Rails\ Projects/
rails new thing
ls
rm -R thing
ls
which brew
which zsh
cd ..
cd 
ls
ls -a
cat .zshrc
cat .zshrc
cat .bash_profile
cat .oh-my-zsh/
cd .oh-my-zsh/
ls
cat .oh-my-zsh.sh
cd 
ls
ls -a
cat .zshrc.backup
echo $ZSH
export ZSH="/Users/joshua/.oh-my-zsh"
echo $ZSH
which rails
ll
```

This might be my old path? `export PATH=/Users/joshua/.npm-global/bin:./bin:./node_modules/.bin:/Users/joshua/.rbenv/shims:/Users/joshua/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/usr/local/sbin`

Anyway, you are a hero if you made it this far and if you have any idea what I should do I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by moving my dotfiles (which contains all my zsh settings) back to the original location. The change was caused by the re-ordering of many folders.

I also restored my PATH back to the old one pasted at the bottom of the question.